# pycharm debugger not working ,breakpoint already given, but it shows frames are not available

Tags: python, pycharm

[debugger not working pycharm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6p8X.png)

debugger got stucked after without execution, breakpoint already given,it show only frames are not available

Comment: Perhaps it is running a loop or the user input is expected? You are debugging `aswin.py`. Could you share this file's content?

Comment: tnku @PavelKarateev